# Create an IQueryable without instantiating a dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am writing a helper class. This helper will give me queries. These queries will be used in multiple parts of my application. This is why I want to put these queries into a common class, accessible from all parts of my projects.

If I choose to work with SQL queries, my helper class will return strings.

But I want to work with Entity Framework. So my helper will return `IQueryable` objects. The problem is I can't create an `IQueryable` object without instantiating a `DbContext`.

Do you know a way to create an `IQueryable` without instantiating a `DbContext` ?

If this is not possible, is there a way for my helper to return parts of queries (filters for example) ?

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at Compiled Queries feature, or create methods that return Expressions of Func type to be able to supply them to the Where method of EF.

Comment: @NazaRN To be clearer to the OP, it needs to be said that `Expression<Func<...,T>>` is very different to `Func<...,T>`, (which I think is what you meant?)

Comment: You'd write your own reusable queries by defining your own extensions to `IQueryable<T>` for specific concrete `T` types which _must_ be Entity Framework entity classes' types; which means your reusable queries project will need to have access to those entity types at compile-time (either in-project, or through a project or assembly reference) - otherwise how can any `GetProductsThatAreRed()` work method without knowing what `class Product` is?

Comment: I do not completely understand what you want to achieve. Maybe you want to implement methods returning Func<DbContext,T>? Thus you could provide queries that you can use when you have a dbcontext.

Comment: I think your ideas are too premature to give any advice on how EF will fit in. It's esp. unclear how you would return `IQueryable` and how using a DbSet would be a *problem* there .